# Dropdown navigation automatic width

Tags: jquery, css, navigation

I have a drop down menu using CSS only.  I want the drop down to have automatic width but it takes on the width of its parent (as expected).

What is the best method to get it to have automatic width? (i.e ignore its parents width) without defining a set width.

Here it is on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8BV2N/3/)

```
nav{ background: #000 ; clear: both ; height: 40px ; padding: 0 10px ; }
nav ul{ list-style: none ; }
nav li{ float: left ; position: relative ; }
nav a{ display: block ; float: left ; color: #fff ; text-decoration: none ; padding-right: 30px ; font-size: 120% ; line-height: 40px ; }
nav div{ display: none ; position: absolute ; background: red ; left: 0 ; top: 40px ; }
nav li:hover div{display: block ; }
```

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            <div>
                <p>example of width not working</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">next</a>
            <div>example</div>
        </li>        
        <li><a href="#">again</a>
            <div>example</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

If it's not possible with CSS, a Javascript/Jquery solution would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `white-space: nowrap;` on the element that shouldn't go to the next line.
It will keep all the words on the same line and not break into a new line so that it takes automatic width.

In your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8BV2N/4/

Also; it is considered best practise to use another ul for your submenu instead of a div. this way search engines can understand the structure of your website better.

Comment: thanks, the reason for the div was that the drop down contains multiple dl's, still best to use ul > li > dl?

Comment: I wouldn't use `dl`'s at all, I would use `ul > li > ul > li`